# PIN input argument loggin/reading

Tags: input, arguments, intel, instrumentation

I'm wondering if any of you guys have experience in reading/logging the input arguments of an instrumented method?

Technically it's so simple and straightforward when the method has some primitive data type as input parameters. For example, `integer` or `double`. However, when it's a more complex data type, like `string`, I faced some weird behavior from pin framework. In nutshell, I cannot recover the original data input.

Below you see my instrumentation function. It simply tries to print the input arguments passed to the instrumented method.

```
VOID start_of_execution(uint64_t hash_name, int type, 
   ADDRINT input_arg1, 
   ADDRINT input_arg2
){

cout << "int arg:" << input_arg1 << endl; // prints the integer input
cout << "string*:" << hex << input_arg2 << endl; // prints the pointer value
cout << "string arg:" << *(reinterpret_cast<string*>(input_arg2)) << endl; // prints nothing!
}
```

Here is the instrumented method which it's the only functionality is to print the input arguments.

```
int sample_method(int i, string* str){
   cout << "-----" << endl;
   cout << "i: " << i << ", str:" << *str <<", ptr:" << str << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Below is the output:

```
$ sudo ../../../pin -t obj-intel64/code/mypin.so -- ./code/a.out
int arg:5
string*:0x1704434923
string arg:
-----
i: 5, str:sample text, ptr:0x1704434923
```

As you see, the integer argument (number 5) has been retrived properly. However, even though the string pointer is valid, PIN wasn't able to recover the string input argument.

Does anybody have an idea about my problem?

Comment: How is this function being used? Where are the arguments coming from? We can guess, but we'd rather not. Show us more of your pintool... (You might be looking for pin_safecopy, but without more information it's hard to know).

Comment: I have added an example, showing the problem. In the instrumentation, I can easily access the original values of integers or pointers passed to the instrumented methods, however, I cannot use it to obtain the string or other complex data type values.
It seems that PIN is not using the standard-library so as I cannot cast the object into a string object. What do you think?